# How to build project using ant, if it has some libraries, used by many modules

Tags: java, android, ant, jar

My application use **ViewPageIndicator**, **HoloEverywhere**, **ActionBarSherlock**, and all it uses *android-support-v4.jar* library. But when I include this library into */libs* folder of each module, it causes build error:

```
com.android.sdklib.build.DuplicateFileException: 
Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK
at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder$JavaAndNativeResourceFilter.checkEntry(ApkBuilder.java:125)
...
```

If I remove these libraries from any module, build failed in this module, because can not find library classes.

How to fix it and build the project?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the modules to build on their own, or do you just need your application to build? Assuming it's the latter, what happens if you include the jar in only your project? Eclipse may not like this since there will be errors in the workspace, but at least with command-line Ant, you can just reference a library project without building it ahead of time and your app should compile, since it will pull in all the classes/resources and build everything at once.

I.e., suppose:

- projectA references libraryProjectB
- projectA depends on libFoo
- libraryProjectB depends on libFoo

Then try:

- put libFoo in projectA
- build projectA only

Not positive this will solve your problem, but I encountered a similar situation with shared C/C++ libraries and leaving them only in the library project solved my own issue, so hopefully this is helpful.